# :active and :focus on anchor is not working for IE and Mozilla

Tags: html, css

In the below HTML code I am trying to achieve color change on current active anchor means once any tab is clicked it should show color(#ffd96b) as its background, it is working fine for Chrome but not working for IE and Mozilla. Not getting why it is happening may be I have missed something, Any help is much appreciated.

```css
.tileMargin {
  margin: 5%;
}
.deviceName {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
.deviceCount {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -3px;
}
.deviceCount >div {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.deviceCount input,
button {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 3px 0px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  appearance: button;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.devicesSmall a:hover div,
.devicesSmall a:hover input,
.devicesSmall a:hover button,
.devicesSmall a:active div,
.devicesSmall a:active input,
.devicesSmall a:active button,
.devicesSmall a:focus div,
.devicesSmall a:focus input,
.devicesSmall a:focus button {
  background-color: #ffd96b !important;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <Title>asd sada asfa</Title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="tileMargin">
        <div class="devicesSmall col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
          <a href="#">
            <div class="deviceName"><span>Mobile</span>
            </div>
            <div class="deviceCount">
              <div>
                <button onclick="addProduct('mobile');">+</button>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="mobile" type="text" value="1" disabled>
              </div>
              <div>
                <button onclick="removeProduct('mobile');">-</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="devicesSmall col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <a href="#">
            <div class="deviceName"><span>Landline</span>
            </div>
            <div class="deviceCount">
              <div>
                <button onclick="addProduct('landline');">+</button>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="landline" type="text" value="1" disabled>
              </div>
              <div>
                <button onclick="removeProduct('landline');">-</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="devicesSmall col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <a href="#">
            <div class="deviceName"><span>Internet</span>
            </div>
            <div class="deviceCount">
              <div>
                <button onclick="addProduct('internet');">+</button>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="internet" type="text" value="0" disabled>
              </div>
              <div>
                <button onclick="removeProduct('internet');">-</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="devicesSmall col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <a href="#">
            <div class="deviceName"><span>IPTV</span>
            </div>
            <div class="deviceCount">
              <div>
                <button onclick="addProduct('Iptv');">+</button>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="Iptv" type="text" value="1" disabled>
              </div>
              <div>
                <button onclick="removeProduct('Iptv');">-</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `:active` doesn't mean the link that is currently active, it means the link that is currently being used (when you click it)

Comment: copied the the code and it works o.k, `:active` means that the color changes while you are pressing the left mouse button on the item. if you will stop pressing the `:active` will not be active. can you please suplly more details to your problem?

Comment: I f you want to change the item color after clicking you can use Jquery toggle. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Is it working on IE as well? 

what if I want to show the background color changed after the click event on the link?

Comment: like css `:visited` ? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp

Comment: yes, it is working on IE as well

Comment: Also it should work like once clicked on second link the first link remove that background color(#ffd96b) and second should be highlighted with the background color(#ffd96b).

Comment: @DavSev: what is the problem then, it is not not working on my end on IE and Mozilla.

Comment: :visited will highlight all the visited links... I want to highlight only on which is clicked..

Comment: What version of IE do you use? Try cleaning cach

Comment: @DavSev : IE11, and what is the version you are using?

Comment: IE 11 as well... have you tried to clean the browser cache?

Comment: @DavSev : yes.. cleared the cache and reset the browser settings as well, but still the same.

Comment: Have you managed to find the problem why it is not showing on IE?

Comment: @DavSev not yet...

Comment: can you upload the files some where?

Comment: @DavSev Code is already placed in  my question above...

Answer (score 1):

It is not that it isnt working in FF or IE, `:active` is applied at the moment when you click the element and DOES NOT preserve it. The styling is removed once you release the click.

Also after you click the link Chrome keeps the focus on the link whereas FF and IE does not. That is why the `:focus` styling is removed after you click it.

To make a link active, add a class `active` in CSS and add/remove the classes according to which link was clicked using JS.

Comment: Thank you for the help.. Could you please help with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Thanks to you all for looking into this issue...

I have found the issue in my code that was creating problem and causing :active and :focus not work as expected. Actually I had placed the form element like input and button under anchor tag, which is not correct implementation according to w3c standards.

Now I have removed all the button and input from inside that "a" tag and its working fine now.